# Expected value of bivariate lognormal spread

Tags: spread, lognormal

I don´t know how to derivate the Expected Value for the following problem:

Suppose that the random vector `(S_1, S_2)` has a bivariate lognormal distribution with parameter vector `(u_1, u_2, v_1, v_2, p)` such that vector `(U_1, U_2)=[(ln{S_1}-u_1)/v_1, (ln{S_2}-u_2)/v_2]` has a standard bivariate normal distribution with correlation p

...
Now, how would you derivate expected positive difference of the bivariate lognormal spread, t.i. :
`E[max(S_1 - S_2, 0)]`?

Answer (score 2):

if they are stocks, this problem is called pricing a Margrabe option and it is generally solved by change of numeraire. Take $S_2$ to be the numeraire. Then the value of the option is
$$
S_2(0) \mathbb{E}_{S_2}( (S_1(T)/S_2(T)-1)_+)
$$
where the expectation is taken in the measure that has $S_1/S_2$ as a martingale. Since it's a martingale and log-normal at time T the expectation is easy to compute and you are done.